# How to Generate PDF Using HTML Templates in iOS with Objective-C

Tags: php, html, ios, pdf

I am creating an `iPad` application that is used to create the `PDF` and then send to server or by email.
I have followed the tutorial from the appcoda:
http://www.appcoda.com/pdf-generation-ios/

However, this tutorial is use the swift, that my application is using the `Objective-C` , how i can change the code from `Swift` to `Objective-C` and used in my application? Then, I tried the tutorial that I am not able to send it as an email. Also, I want to know how to send the PDF to the server via `PHP`.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: code formatting, extra space removed

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

1. Create the PDF in the server.
2. Send the PDF as an email attachment.

:)

Comment: Thank you forum you answer.  Is here have the tutorial about the pdf created by server?  Could you tell me